# make a 2D matrix of strings to match mesh coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a structured mesh. The mesh has coordinates (X,Y), but each mesh cell also has an alphanumerical code assigned.
The mesh X and Y coordinates are generated as 2D arrays with meshgrid.

The series with the alphanumerical codes looks like this

```
Index   Code
0       aa1
1       aa2
2       aa3
3       aa4
4       bb1
5       bb2
6       bb3
7       bb4
8       ab1
9       ab2
10      ab3
11      ab4
....    .....
```

My thought was to make a 2D array of the alphanumerical codes so that the row and column index of each element will correspond to the same row and column index of the X and Y 2D arrays.

the alphanumerical values are in a pandas series of the same length as the size of the X and Y 2D arrays. I need to slice the alphanumerical values every nth element (so take for instance 0 to 2 and make this the first row) and form the first row of the 2D array and continue like this filling the rest.

and in the end i want to have this:

```
0     0           1         2
1     aa1         aa2       aa3        
2     aa4         bb1       bb2
3     bb3         bb4       ab1
4     ab2         ab3       ab4
.....................
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work?
i managed to get to this:

```
interval = 2
alphanum = [array[i:i+interval] for i in range(len(df.series))[::interval]]
```

which gives me a list of series and not a 2D array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.array_split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) or even [`numpy.split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) to split the arrays into multiple sub-arrays. But the former does not raise an exception if an equal division cannot be made.

```
In [2]: np.array(np.array_split(df['Code'].values, 4))
Out[2]: 
array([['aa1', 'aa2', 'aa3'],
       ['aa4', 'bb1', 'bb2'],
       ['bb3', 'bb4', 'ab1'],
       ['ab2', 'ab3', 'ab4']], dtype=object)
```

**EDIT :**

You mean like this?

```
In [5]: np.array(np.array_split(df.as_matrix(columns=['Code']), 4))
Out[5]: 
array([[['aa1'],
        ['aa2'],
        ['aa3']],

       [['aa4'],
        ['bb1'],
        ['bb2']],

       [['bb3'],
        ['bb4'],
        ['ab1']],

       [['ab2'],
        ['ab3'],
        ['ab4']]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: this is very helpful,i was not aware of the np.array_split function.
But like this i get multiple arrays where i would actually like a single array with all the subarrays created with your solution as row in the that array. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Actually now that i think about it, i could simply define an 1D array based on the series values and then reshape that array to a 2D one according to the dimensions needed right?

Comment: Do you want it to be outputted as a dataframe object?

Comment: I am not sure. Would that make it more easy to work with? I am planning to generate several datasets (thousands) in the same structure and make some plots
What would be your advice for this? Stick with pandas, or go numpy?

Comment: And if i would like to have the resulting 2D matrix in pandas, how can that be handled? I am not sure where to look for this

Comment: If your end goal is to do visualization, you could have one large dataframe of, as you said thousands of rows, which could be plotted with `pandas` inbuilt `df.plot()`. Also dataframes are much more manageable than creating a large number of numpy arrays.

Comment: It's as simple as `pd.DataFrame(np.array_split(df['Code'].values, 4))`.

Comment: still need to do some tweaking but i think i can make this work for me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you know the length of each row you can use just a list.
You can make the 2D array in "your head" and convert the coordinates into their position in an array.

**Example**:

You have got a row_length x column_length grid, therefore you have a list with a row_length*column_length entries.
To access a specific coordinate you access the following entry of the list:

```
Pos(x|y) = mygrid[xcoord*rowlength+columnlength]
```

**Explanation/Clarification**:

Instead of using an actual 2D array, you can just use a 1D list. If you know the size of each row, that isn't a problem but instead, increases the speed your program is working with. Let's assume we have got a 3x3 grid containing a letter at each position, our coordinates will look like that: (0|0, 0|1, 0|2, 1|0, 1|1, ...)

We could represent this grid with:

```
      0          1         2

0    'a'        'q'       'x'

1    'm'        'f'       'b'  

2    'l'        's'       'r'
```

Or, instead of creating an actual 2D grid, we just create a 1D array.

```
data = ['a', 'q', 'x', 'm', 'f', 'b', 'l', 's', 'r']
```

To get the index of a specific coordinate we can now multiply the row_number with the length of each row and add the column_number to it.

For example, to access the coordinate (2|1) of the grid above, we can just access:

```
data[2*3+1]
```

If you check both values, you will see that both are delivering the letter 's' as it should.

Comment: i am not sure i understand this. Could you explain it a bit further?

Comment: Have added a clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However i think i prefer the solution with the matrix. I think that in the long run this will simplify my workload as my database will become quite massive

Comment: Yeah, that suggestion works only if you get all data from start (or at least if the length of each row won't increase in the lifetime of the project)