# Generate multiple 2D arrays from column data of a pandas dataframe and store them in a data structure

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have several versions of this type of DataFrame.

My idea was to structure each individual value column in a 2D mesh/array **for each time step**. These 2D arrays should be sequenced by increasing TIME values and stored as a separate dataset (in pandas or numpy??) per variable.
This way i could call the value and load all the TIME instances of it. If i plot these consecutive time steps it should give me a temporal representation of the 2D space (a moving image of the 2D space in time) for each variable.

```
INDEX TIME ELEM   var1   var2    var3 ....
    0    0   h1  0.555   0.97   1.555
    1    0   t5      0    0.8     1.2
    2    0   y7      1      7       1
  ...
  300   15   h1    0.6  0.477       0
  301   15   t5    0.9  0.777       1
  302   15   y7  0.555  0.897       5
  ...
  800   23   h1     20      7       2
  801   23   t5      5      7       5
  802   23   y7    0.1      3      55
  ...
 1010   58   h1      9    0.7      11
 1011   58   t5     10    977       6
 1012   58   y7      5     71      52 
  ...
```

Hierarchically what i want to achieve is essentially this data structure, where each variable is stored in a 2D array :

- Full dataset (dataframe)

  - Sub-dataset version (dataframe)

    - Time instance (dataframe)

      - var1 (2D array)
      - var2 (2D array)
      - var3 (2D array)

My first idea was to do [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) TIME and ELEM. But i don't think this is the way to go. I have also looked into the [melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) function but that doesn't seem to cut it either.

Logically i think i first need to slice the data per unique TIME values, then reshape each variable column of that slice based on element code to a 2D matrix/array as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696546/make-a-2d-matrix-of-strings-to-match-mesh-coordinates). Lastly each 2D matrix/array should be added in a datastructure as discussed above. How could i make this work?

My understanding is that ideally the data structure should be in pandas for increased efficiency of operations and broadcasting. Is there a better way? I have looked into panels but it's not so clear yet

This is what i got so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# read the csv file
b = pd.read_csv('D:/myfile.csv', skipinitialspace=False, skiprows=0)

# remove possible empty spaces from the headers
b.rename(columns=lambda x:x.strip(), inplace=True)

# extract unique times and variable names
times = b.TIME.unique()

#make an empty list
listt = []

# for each time instance
for i in range(len(times)):
    # generate the sub-dataset for each uniqe time
    foo = b.loc[b.TIME==times[i]]
    # re-extract the column names for each iteration
    colnames=b.columns.unique().tolist()

    # for each columnname in the dataset
    for k in range(len(colnames)):
        # reshape and assign the reshaped arrays inside the colnames list
        colnames[k] = np.reshape(foo[colnames[k]], (-1,51)) 
    # append each TIME instance with it's respective structured data to the list    
    listt.append(colnames)

# convert the generated list to a 4D panel
mypanel = pd.Panel4D(listt)
```

This way my indexes are numerical so i am not able to keep the actual values for unique time and the column names which is not optimal. I have the feeling this can be done better and in a more efficient way, just don't know how
Suggestions are welcome.... :-)

Comment: Can you add desired output from your sample?

Comment: Have you looked into panda's panels?

Comment: @jezrael i am not sure i know how to do that and this is part of my problem in finding a solution to this....

Comment: @Khris nope i haven't. But i am looking into them now.....Didn't even know they existed

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe Multiindex can help - `df = df.set_index(['TIME','ELEM'])`

Comment: I dont understand `(structured by ELEM codes)` for each `val`

Comment: @jezrael the ELEM codes translate to coordinates. So based on the ELEM code i can structure the 2D array and assign the correct value of the val columns to the correct 2D coordinates
Multiindex seems promising, will look into it

Comment: Phuuu, 4D panel I never use. and it looks like you need numpy more as pandas, so unfortuntely I have no idea how I can improve your solution. :(